# Disable Animation in ModernUI Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, modern-ui

I'd like to use the gauge chart to display a dynamic value. My event updates the datacontext frequently. The problem is the animation of the controls.

How Do I disable the animation or update the value without triggering the "start" animation?

ModernUI Charts: http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get informed how do you ask a good question. Please take a look on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) too to read about tags and whether you should use them in question title.